# Getting Img Tag from RSS Description

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I currently have a couple of RSS feeds which hide their images within the pesky description tag.

I'm trying to get only the image src from the description, but I seem to be failing with every solution on here.

```
<description><![CDATA[Duration: 604 sec<br>URL: http://www.test.com/videos/998879/surf.mpeg<br><img src="http://test.test.com/320x240/461/1055458.jpg"><br><iframe src="http://test.com/embed/998879" frameborder=0 width=650 height=518 scrolling=no></iframe>]]></description>
```

As you can see it's a bit stuck in there!

```
function echo_url($string) {
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);
return $match[0][0];
}
```

Currently using this function to try and retrieve the image but no luck!

Any help would be brilliant!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$description = '<description><![CDATA[Duration: 604 sec<br>URL: http://www.test.com/videos/998879/surf.mpeg<br><img src="http://test.test.com/320x240/461/1055458.jpg"><br><iframe src="http://test.com/embed/998879" frameborder=0 width=650 height=518 scrolling=no></iframe>]]></description>';
$html = str_get_html($description);
echo $html->find('img', 0)->src;
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The description is dynamic within a variable, will your code still work with it?

Comment: Yes, this code will search through any string and find the img tag in it.

Comment: @Jonathan — In a variable? Like the example code in the answer?